# connecting android application with Android Wear Clock in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, wear-os

I have an Android Studio application.I need to connect my Android-Wear with Samsung Clock.The Usb connection is available.But the adb connection is not available in Android Wear Clock.

I followed the following links

1) http://androidnews.co.in/2014/07/06/enable-usb-debugging-android-wear/
2) http://techegis.com/enable-adb-debugging-android-wear/

Where i am going wrong.Can anyone guide me. I will be thankful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Open cmd (if use windows).

2) Go to your adb directory `(c:/dev/sdk/platform-tools/)`

for example.

3) Type: `adb -forvard tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub`

4) Then type: `adb connect localhost:4444`

*If dont work kill adb.exe and try again*

Comment: I tried like what u said.I guess you have been working with Android Wear application for couple of months.I am a StartBie in it.If possible,Can you guide me.

Comment: @Mobile, ok i can guid you.
Please, close eclipse/android studio and notify that adb.exe is killed.
Then connect the wear to mobile device.
Then open `Android wear` app on phone, go to preferences and say me what u see in line `bluetooth debugging` ?

Comment: @Mobile skype: podlinovav